# Wait till any of 2 element is found on screen(Appium)

Tags: appium

I need to explore wait command in appium. After login, there can be 2 scenarios and I want my code to wait until either of those 2 elements is found.

Comment: Have fun exploring i'd say. It looks like you are asking us to write it for you, which is not the purpose of StackOverflow. Please read the the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and improve your question with those guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath for these two locators by using or operator in xpath string

> String xpath="//*[contains(@text, 'Log In') **or**
>   contains(@resource-id,'/drawerImgBtn')]";

```
Wait waitForElement = new FluentWait(automationDriver.appiumDriver).withTimeout(timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
MobileElement element=(MobileElement) waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathString)));
if(element.isDisplayed())
            {

                return true;
            }
            else
            {

                return false;
```

}